# How to collect the value corresponding to a field of an array/list of named tuples

Tags: python

I am new to Python, in the process of migrating from MATLAB. I was using the `namedtuple` class the following way.

```
from collections import namedtuple
import numpy as np
MyStruct = namedtuple("MyStruct", "field1 field2 field3")
d = []
d.append(MyStruct(field1=np.array(3,'int'),field2=np.array(4,'int'),field3=np.array(5,'int')))
d
d.append(MyStruct(field1=np.array(4,'int'),field2=np.array(5,'int'),field3=np.array(6,'int')))
```

Here `d` is a 2-element list of `namedtuple` objects. What I want is to obtain an array of all `field1` values through all the elements of `d` in a nifty way without the need to iterate through the elements of `d`. Something similar to MATLAB, where we put square brackets around an array of structures.

I'd appreciate any insights into this matter.

Srini

Comment: If all your data has one type and has a regular shape, use `numpy` directly else if different data types, check out http://pandas.pydata.org/

Comment: I want to create an array of C/MATLAB structs with certain fields.  All I want is to extract all the values, which are numerics, corresponding to a particular field from the array of structures.  The structure is essential for me.  I hope I was able to convey my situation.

Comment: What I was trying to hint at is that the `numpy` array is n-dimensional, so if all you have is NxM data of one type you should just create a `numpy` array directly and not care for other types.

Comment: I understand.  But I would like to annotate each dimension of the N dimension of the MX1 data through a field name.  Also, not all fields are of the same numpy type.  Some are int and others are floats.

Comment: The answer below should be all you need, @user3317287 , but for future reference, this guide may be worth bookmarking: http://wiki.scipy.org/NumPy_for_Matlab_Users

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some options:

```
In [31]: x = np.array([(3,4,5),(4,5,6)],dtype=[('field1','i'),('field2','i'), ('field3', 'i')])

In [32]: x['field2']
Out[32]: array([4, 5])

In [33]: x = np.array([(3, 4, 5), (4, 5, 6)])

In [34]: x[:, 1]
Out[34]: array([4, 5])

In [35]: x = np.array([MyStruct(field1=3, field2=4, field3=5), MyStruct(field1=4, field2=5, field3=6)])

In [36]: x[:, 1]
Out[36]: array([4, 5])
```

Or if you explicitly need different columns to have different types, after having `import pandas as pd`:

```
In [41]: x = pd.DataFrame([MyStruct(field1=3, field2=4, field3=5), MyStruct(field1=4, field2=5, field3=6)], columns=['field1', 'field2', 'field3'])

In [42]: x.field2
Out[42]: 
0    4
1    5
Name: field2, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thanks, I like the second option using pandas.  I was wondering how to get rid of the leading 0 and 1 indices.  I don't know too much about Pandas, I'll look into it.  I was wondering if it is light weight, memory efficient is retrieving and storing data. Also, I wanted to know if Pandas work natively with numpy objects.  Thanks for your time.  I'd appreciate if you could answer these few questions.

Comment: pandas is built upon numpy I think, so they work fine together and in similar ways.

Comment: Yeah, I verified that.  Thanks for your prompt help.  Since, I am coming from MATLAB, it is a little hard, frustrating to gather information for my purposes for what I want to achieve in Python.  Thanks to you guys, I feel much better.

Answer (score 1):

This is what list comprehensions are for:

```
field1vals = [x.field1 for x in d]
```

Comment: Thanks!  Now how do I convert the list of numpy scalars into a numpy array? Is there a single command for achieving that?